# Shorten regex any character including whitespace, alphanum, special char, and unicode

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I want to match any character after some word (limit is an example).

```
✔ nnn : am
-limitaaaa
ça UNICODE HERE
sdasdsadaw
✔ UNICODE HERE
limitaaaa,.@#!~`%$&*()[]{}|\+=-_?/'":;.><,
777723xx sss fff s :,
```

my current regex. https://regex101.com/r/bSbUBG/2

```
/limit+([.*\s\w\d\p{M}\p{L}\p{S},:@#!~`%$&()\[\]\{\}\|\\+=\-_\?\/\'";><]+)/
```

My regex **works**, but it looks too long. My question is can I make it shorter?

Note: If you need to know what kind of language that I used, I using PHP for this.

Comment: Maybe `(?s)limit(.+)`? In PHP, `'~limit(.+)~s'` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/R107iF/2))? Looks like you want to match any 1 or more chars after `limit`.

Comment: You could use [`limit+([\s\S]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/bSbUBG/3), which is basically every character including newlines. You could also write `limit(.+)` in `DOTALL` mode.

Comment: WTF. i really try that before. but i'm sure thats was not work. but thats working. miracle. @Jan Can u post it as an answer? i will check it

Comment: So all you missed was an `s` modifier.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i think i dont need that. Thank you for your suggestion. I appreciate that

Comment: No need for a workaround like `[\s\S]`, PCRE has `s` modifier support, and you do need it more than `[\s\S]`. Even if you have a longer pattern and this is part of it, all you need is `limit((?s:.+))`. Do not use `[\s\S]` if you are using PCRE.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thats works. with `s` modifier. https://regex101.com/r/bSbUBG/6 You both are awesome.

Comment: Do you want to match word also (limit in your example)? Or only what is after it?

Comment: @virolino no. I can make it by myself, i just want to know how to make it short, but Wiktor and Jan give me the answer. thanks bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either use

```
limit([\s\S]+)
```

Or

```
limit(.+)
```

in `DOTALL` mode (`s` flag).

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/bSbUBG/3) or [**this one for the latter**](https://regex101.com/r/bSbUBG/5).

Comment: 6 minutes to go. i'll check it ASAP. thanks for quick answer